# How to cut a specific character in a file in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ip, character, cut

I have a problem. I have a file. This file contains about 100 rows and each row is an IPv6 address. My task is to cut the 0 where it stands first place of a block or remove the whole block if it contains only 0.
Here is an example: 
ORIGINAL:

```
2001:0db8:03cd:0000:0000:ef45:0006:0123
```

MODIFIED:

```
2001:db8:3cd:::ef45:6:123
```

Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sub(/^0+/,x,$i)}1' FS=: OFS=: file
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/(^|:)0+/$1/g' file
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. Can you give me a similar code that i could use in powershell?